# How to get the current user with get_redis_instance?

Tags: django, redis, channel

I'm using channels==1.1.7 and asgi-redis==1.4.3. I want to get the user of the current session with this command:

```
user = get_redis_instance().get(id)
```

with get_redis_instance function defined as follow:

```
def get_redis_instance():
    from myproject.asgi import channel_layer
    return channel_layer._connection_list[0]
```

but it returns none!!

the code above is inside a consumer:

```
class MyprojectWebsocket(WebsocketConsumer, WebsocketAuth):

    http_user = True
    channel_session = True
    channel_session_user = True

     def authenticate(self):
        if user.is_authenticated
        if get_redis_instance().get(id) != None:
            return True
        else:
             return False
    def connect(self, message, id):
        self.message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
        user = get_redis_instance().get(id)
        print("user: {}".format(user))
        if not self.authenticate(id):
            self.message.reply_channel.send({"text": json.dumps(
                {'status': False, 'message': 'You must login to the system!'})}, immediately=True)
            self.message.reply_channel.send({"accept": False})
```

with id is the id of the current user

Comment: why would the user session be saved in redis? what are you using asgi-redis for exactly? how have you configures your django-sessions? where are you trying to rung the code you're showing above? in a consumer? What is `id`?

Comment: I'm using channels==1.1.7 in my Django project to handle WebSockets, and to be able to allow talking between different instances, I'm using channels_redis, which is an offical Django-maintained layer that uses Redis as a transport. Yes, it is a consumer.

Comment: but isn't the user just `self.scope['user']` inside the channel`WebsocketConsumer`? (or `get_user(self.scope)`)

Comment: I tried the command tha you have already mentioned get_user(self.scope)) and I get this error: NameError: name 'get_user' is not defined

Comment: You need to import it of course, don't remember exactly where it is but I guess in `channels.auth`. Look it up in the channels documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your help !!